# How to completely remove the .invisible div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide a `select` tag and just show it when needed.

So I use the `.invisible` of bootstrap but the result is, even it is hidden it still consume spaces.

```
  <div class="row invisible">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg col-lg-12">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="for-select" class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Items</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select name="for-select" id="for-select" class="form-control">
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What wrong with this question? Just less than 5 minutes after posting and got a down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.d-none` instead of `.invisible`.

`.d-none` will use the css property `display: none;`.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

`.invisible` uses `visibility: hidden;` which can be useful to hide content but keep it for audio readers.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/visibility/

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between visibility and display:

Visibility makes something invisible without changing the dimensions. Display changes the display hence it will not take any space.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/visibility/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Use one of the display classes instead of the visibility classes.

Answer (score 0):

use class .hidden instead of .invisible 
and change remove class .hidden when you want to display

Comment: Nope, it wont work. and .hidden class is not existing anymore on Bootstrap 4.